# Fetch mongo nested attributes as columns

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below is my mongo structure

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfbc18e28198e2f74e1d2d0"), 
    "address" : {
        "building" : "1007", 
        "coord" : [
            -73.856077, 
            40.848447
        ], 
        "street" : "Morris Park Ave", 
        "zipcode" : "10462"
    }, 
    "borough" : "Bronx", 
    "cuisine" : "Bakery"
}
```

On firing db.Restaurant.find({"address.building":"1007"},{"address.building":1,"address.street":1,"address.zipcode":1})
 query it gives result as

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfbc18e28198e2f74e1d2d0"), 
    "address" : {
        "building" : "1007", 
        "street" : "Morris Park Ave", 
        "zipcode" : "10462"
    }
}
```

So it's still returning result as nested documents but I want to get those nested attributes as column name and don't want nested structure . How can I modify this query for that?[image: expected output image]

Answer (score 3):

`find` query can only limit the fields. If you want to reshape the data you need to use `aggregation` instead

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "address.building": "1007" }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$address" }},
  { "$project": { "coord": 0 }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following aggregate. It first matches any of your conditions and then projects the necessary fields, without any nesting.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $match : {
            "address.building":"1007"
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            building : "$address.building",
            street : "$address.street",
            zipcode : "$address.zipcode"
        }
    }
])
```

Output :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfbc18e28198e2f74e1d2d0"),
    "building" : "1007",
    "street" : "Morris Park Ave",
    "zipcode" : "10462"
}
```

Let me know if this helped!